# Overflow: auto always show scroll

Tags: css, overflow, padding

I have a parent div, I set max heigth, overflow auto for it. And it have two children div. But I saw the height of parent div equals sum of two children's height.
And It only working when I add padding bottom to Parent div or Last children div.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Kindly provide your code snippet

Comment: Have you taken into account any default settings the browser may be adding (e.g. padding/margin)?

Comment: Please provide some code example;

Comment: My code is: 
<div class="pb-1" [ngStyle]="{ 'max-height': 'calc(77vh - 100px)', 'overflow': 'auto' }">
    <div fxLayout="column">
      somethings...
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column">
      somethings...
    </div>
  </div>
Sorry because my shortcoming. I add class 'mb-1' in parent div to overflow working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the children have in sum bigger height, you should increase the size of the parent.

I recommend you to learn about flex-box, here's a good website for that [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will check it.

Comment: Please mark as "answered".